# Text color change on hover over button

Tags: css, text, colors, hover

I am trying to change the color of the text inside the button on hover.

I can make the button itself change color, but I want the button text to change color too.

Here is my current css:

```
button,
input.button,
a.button,
input[type="submit"] {
background:#2e77ae;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5590bd, #2e77ae);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5590bd, #2e77ae);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5590bd, #2e77ae);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5590bd, #2e77ae);
background: linear-gradient(top, #5590bd, #2e77ae);
border-color:#2e77ae;}

button:hover,
input.button:hover,
a.button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover{

    background:#E6D332;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    border-color:#2e77ae;}



button:focus,
input.button:focus,
a.button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus { 
    background-color:#E6D332;}
```

Comment: to change text color use `color:#color;`

Comment: to change text-color you  need to add this `color:#455667`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS property `color` controls the text color in elements generically. In your case, to change the color on hover, use the `:hover` specifier;

```
input[type = "submit"]:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
    //you can add more styles to be applied on hover
}
```

Note that you can as well specify the color using the `rgb(x, y, z)` format. Here's a little demo to illustrate: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zr5j/show/). You can play around with the demo and view the source here: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zr5j/).

I hope that helped!

Comment: thanks for the help - it still doesn't work - am i doing something wrong:       button:hover,
 input.button:hover,
 a.button:hover,
 input[type="submit"]:hover{
 
  background:#E6D332;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
  border-color:#2e77ae;
  color :#2e77ae;}

Comment: @StephenO'connor Please take a look at this: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Zr5j/2/). This uses your same code, and it works on `hover`.

Comment: thanks - it is not working on my page for some reason - i don't know why but thanks for your help @Abody97

Comment: @StephenO'connor Is your page live? Can you provide a link to it? If not, can you please post your full HTML/CSS?

Comment: @StephenO'connor It's because you have a rule: `color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;` remove the `!important` part and it'll work.

Comment: @StephenO'connor If it worked don't forget to "tick" the answer as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the color of the text, use the CSS `color` property, like

```
input[type="submit"]:hover{
   color :#E6D332; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p.one{
    color: DarkBlue}
p.one:hover{
    color: yellow}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Css Help</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <p class="one">Example TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample TextExample Text<p>
    </body>
<html>
```

Here is what I do:

```
a:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

You can change the 'a' to whatever such as a paragraph 'p' or specify it the html file with a class

```
<p class="one">Example</p>
```

Them in CSS file do:

```
p.one:hover{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I hope I could Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn:hover h3{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

You can write the selectors for elements (such as text) within the `<button>` after `.btn:hover` to update those specific elements css properties when hovering on the button.

Answer (score -1):

`color:#(insert text color)` Put this in

Comment: in the hover section
`input[type="submit"]:hover{

    background:#E6D332;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #E6D332, #E6D332);
    border-color:#2e77ae;
    color:#(insert text color)}`

Comment: @StephenO'connor You should use capital letters I think. So #2E77AE, not #2e77ae

Comment: Does matter t #2e77ae OR #2E77AE,