# Change text inside button on :hover

Tags: html, css, onhover

How to change "Contacte-nos" text color on :hover?

```css
.popmake-contacte-nos {

  background-color: #fffff7;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popmake-contacte-nos:hover {
  background-color: #3c8b96;
}
```

```html
<button class="popmake-contacte-nos">Contacte-nos</button>
```

Comment: ehh ... simply `color` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text color change on hover over button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139546/text-color-change-on-hover-over-button)

Comment: Temani,

I swear i "obviously" tried, ( color: white; ) yesterday, and it didn't work!

Some glitch or something. Anyway i am sorry wasting your time for such a thing. But it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `color` to your hover selector

```css
.popmake-contacte-nos {

  background-color: #fffff7;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popmake-contacte-nos:hover {
  background-color: #3c8b96;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="popmake-contacte-nos">Contacte-nos</button>
```